# Changing Ionic 2 app files on Application Data folder

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm starting with Ionic 2 and had create an app (not on store) and need help with a function for my clients.

I want my app to be able to download a package, with images and configurations that changes the application icon, background and other things.

Is it possible to do that?

I'll send specific files to specific users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds heavy for a hybrid framework like Ionic. You can definitely install the File plugin to enable users to download packages and have metadata dependent on that package, like backgrounds, page images, etc.. However, app-specific icons and splash screens require application store updates.

Comment: Troy, I will use something like in-app purchases to enable the user to download the package from my server. Do you think its possible for the app replace the standard files for the ones I send? At least the phone app-drawer icon... :/